# React Native Button onPress function example

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the difference between using the two and when should I use one over the other

```
<Button onPress={this.refreshData}>
```

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.refreshData()}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this if you don't need to pass an argument to your function :

```
<Button onPress={this.refreshData}>
```

Doing this `<Button onPress={()=>this.refreshData()}>` may break optimizations.
From React doc:

> Using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may break optimizations based on strict identity comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extract from React Docs.

You can use an arrow function to wrap around an event handler and pass parameters:

`<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(id)} />`

This is equivalent to calling .bind:

`<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, id)} />`

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html